# How do I put variables in the dictionary name?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I'm trying to make a dictionary name with a variable in it to distinguish between different dictionaries.

I've tried this:

```
str(y) + dictionary['z'] = Z
```

but I get 'SyntaxError: can't assign to operator'

Comment: What do you expect this to do?

Comment: Put all the dictionaries in a dictionary, so you can look them up using a string.

Comment: Exactly, @ekhumoro. Bob, don't dynamically create variables like this. This is what data structures are for.

Comment: you should never do what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to use an empty class or the similar but slightly more sophisticated `SimpleNamespace` from the `types` module.

```
from types import SimpleNamespace

bag = SimpleNamespace()
bag.dict1 = {'somekey': 'somevalue'}
bag.dict2 = {'otherkey': 'othervalue'}
```

etc.

This is functionally roughly equivalent to but tends to be a bit more readable than using a dictionary for `bag`: compare `bag.dict1['somekey']` to `bag['dict1']['somekey']`

Another advantage is that autocompleters will typically support attributes but not strings. So if you are in a shell or editor with autocompletion
you can type `bag.d` and then hit `tab` to get `bag.dict` but this does not work with `bag['d`

If you need access by both literal strings and string variables an almost empty class is more flexible:

```
class name_space:
    def __checkkey__(self, key):
        # better safe than sorry
        if key.startswith('_') or key.endswith('_') or not key.isidentifier():
            raise ValueError(f"Unsupported key: {key}")
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        self.__checkkey__(key)
        return self.__dict__.__getitem__(key)
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self.__checkkey__(key)
        return self.__dict__.__setitem__(key, value)
    def __delitem__(self, key):
        self.__checkkey__(key)
        return self.__dict__.__delitem__(key)
```

Now you can do:

```
bag = name_space()
key = 'dict1'
bag[key] = {}
bag.dict1['somekey'] = 'somevalue'
```

etc.